# Firebase Bucketname Not Available

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm having a weird problem with Firebase in Android. I'm trying to upload a photo to Firebase Storage and I'm getting the following error:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The supplied bucketname is not available to this project.
```

At this line of code:

```
StorageReference mStorageRef = mFirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://mooseandroid-a9f96.appspot.com");
```

I'm sure that the bucketname is the same as the one in the console. I even tried with a bucketname that works fine in iOS with Swift. I also changed the rules to public so anyone can read and write to this storage bucket. The realtime database works fine for this project. I'm running out of options right now, don't even know what else I could be trying.

Here's the whole piece of code:

```
FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference mStorageRef = mFirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://mooseandroid-a9f96.appspot.com");
final StorageReference photoRef = mStorageRef.child("posts_images/mooseImg" + getCurrentDateTime() + ".jpg");
UploadTask uploadTask = photoRef.putBytes(data);
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
});
```

And here's the whole error:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The supplied bucketname is not available to this project.
     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.zzb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.zzz(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(Unknown Source)
     at com.moose.android.AddPostActivity.onClick(AddPostActivity.java:163)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10888)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22541)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: use `StorageReference mStorageReference =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts_images/mooseImg").child("put your image name here");` and for storing file just write `mStorageReference.putBytes(data);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage.html#getReferenceFromUrl(java.lang.String)) for `getReferenceFromUrl(String fullUrl)` states:

> An error is thrown if fullUrl is not associated with the FirebaseApp
>   used to initialize this FirebaseStorage

Use this code to see the bucket name in your `FirebaseApp`:

```
    FirebaseOptions opts = FirebaseApp.getInstance().getOptions();
    Log.i(TAG, "Bucket = " + opts.getStorageBucket());
```

I expect it will not be `mooseandroid-a9f96.appspot.com` and will instead be the `storage_bucket` value in the `project_info` section of your `google-services.json` file:

```
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "816275527980",
    "firebase_url": "https://project-8693710910123456789.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "project-8693710910123456789",
    "storage_bucket": "project-8693710910123456789.appspot.com"
  },
```

Comment: this answer helped me, but just to note, if your google-services.json file is correct but you're still getting compile errors, ensure your firebase.init() call is also using the correct "storage_bucket" value.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone changes the bucket url afterwards just clean and rebuild the android project, it solved the issue for me.

For cleaning go to Build tab on top nav bar in android studio -> Click Clean Project.

For rebuilding again go to Build tab on top nav bar in android studio -> Click Rebuild Project.

Comment: The OP (and other users) might find your answer more helpful if it included a detailed explanation of how to "clean and rebuild the android project."