# How to diplay image from firebase using only its name

Tags: android, firebase

```
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference gsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://bacpoche-5ecb0.appspot.com/natio/agr-svt-2009-6-cr.jpg");
    Glide.with(this )
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(gsReference)
            .into(t);
```

But it shows  "Unfortunately YourApp has stopped".

I already have internet permission in manifest file. Below is the Error

The moniteur//E/

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aitelred.redouane.tstv7/com.aitelred.redouane.tstv7.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The supplied bucketname is not available to this project.
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The supplied bucketname is not available to this project.
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.zzz(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(Unknown Source)
       at com.aitelred.redouane.tstv7.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Bucketname Not Available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645018/firebase-bucketname-not-available)

Comment: Tnx.. how can i fix it

Comment: Did you read the duplicate question?

Comment: Yes  i did.. and i got my bucket name from json file... But it still nothing is displayed      StorageReference mStorageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://"+opts.getStorageBucket());

        final StorageReference photoRef = mStorageRef.child("natio/agr-svt-2008-6-cr.jpg");

   t=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ima);
        Glide.with(this )
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                .load(photoRef )
                .into(t);